# Ruby unpack to the hex representation of multiple 8bit addresses?

Tags: ruby, unpack

I am reading a file which looks like:

```
0025be60  24 b3 10 80 00 b4 10 80  a4 b4 10 80 08 b5 10 80  |$...............|
0025be70  94 b5 10 80 9c b7 10 80  40 b9 10 80 e4 b9 10 80  |........@.......|
0025be80  e0 bf 10 80 94 c0 10 80  f4 cc 10 80 54 cd 10 80  |............T...|
0025be90  44 d9 10 80 88 d9 10 80  30 da 10 80 88 db 10 80  |D.......0.......|
0025bea0  44 dc 10 80 d0 e3 10 80  6c e6 10 80 d0 e8 10 80  |D.......l.......|
```

but am having a hard time converting it into an array of hex vaiables. I would like the following:

```
x = [0x24b31080, 0x00b41080, 0xa4b41080, 0x08b51080 ...
```

but am having a problem.  I thought file_contents.unpack("H8*) would work, but that only returns the first value... Any unpack experts out there?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to transform the data a bit more. One way to do this is to use `gsub` on your input stream to remove spaces. This is illustrated here:

```
lines.collect do |line|
  line.gsub(/ /, '').unpack('H8H8H8')
end
```

If you want to ignore part of the line, you can always scope it a bit better:

```
lines.collect do |line|
  line[10, 48].gsub(/ /, '').unpack('H8H8')
end.flatten
```

This is taking 48 characters starting at offset 10 in the string and unpacking those. The `flatten` at the end will convert the two-level array structure into a single level.

Comment: Wouldn't `delete(' ')` be easier than `gsub` in this case?

Comment: my mistake. what was displayed above was the contents of the file in a hex editor.... i can read the file fine by simply opening it, and calling .read. the real question was how to get the entire contents of the file (after the .read) into an array of 8bit addresses.

Comment: That's a different question altogether. What you want is `data.unpack('N*')` which should extract your numbers. There's other ways of packing 32-bit ints that you might need to experiment with if that's not the right endian type, but they're [all documented](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/unpack).